# Access Class variables in Web User Controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Class With one Property and around 6 Public Methods (nothing is static/shared).

My aspx pages set's the Class property to some value, as soon as value is set I can Access Class Methods within the aspxPage, now thats fine. I have 3 web user controls within my aspx page, I need to access few of the Class methods within these web  user controls, I dont really want to create the new instance of class within each of those user controls.

For Example url has the Category Code 25, when 25 passed to Class, Class have different methods to create Breadcrumb, SEO friendly URL's etc....and different user controls with page are performing different tasks, for Example Class.CreateMenu, Class.PageTitle etc.

So what would be the best way where I can institate the class within my aspx page ONCE and have my web user controls access its members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to instantiate the class in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` method and save it to `Session` or `ViewState` so  *this* reference can be available to `user controls`.

```
Session["myObj"]=new MyClass();
```

and read `bounded` object,

```
if(Session["myObj"]!=null){
 MyClass obj=Session["myObj"] as MyClass;
 if(obj!=null){

 }
}
```

Alternatively add public property/method to each user control.

```
public MyClass Data {get;set;}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(Data!=null)
  Label1.Text = Data.Foo;
}
```

and assign object reference from within the page event handler (Page_Load)

```
MyClass obj=new MyClass();
UserControl1.Data=obj;
UserControl2.Data=obj;
```

Comment: any chance of doing it without using SESSION/VIEWSTATE? this will put extra pressure on web server. in Classic Asp it was so easy...we used to declare variable at top of page and all includes files were able to access it throughout the page.

Comment: if my user control is within Content Page of a Master page then what should I do. I guess I can expose some public properties to user control (as suggested above) and then access them on master page? or have a hidden field within user control and then access it within master page. 
Can a master page access a Property of user control if its within a CONTENT page?

Answer (score 0):

I would handle that - if possible in your case - to write the method that handles the class in your .ascx user control , then call that method, passing the class to the method from the aspx page.

The control gets rendered first, before the class actually gets set in the aspx page , so your only other option is to save the class variable as a session or cookie or hidden field as the other answer suggests.

in aspx , creating new instance of user control

```
   <asp:PaymentInformation ID="PaymentInformation1" runat="server" />
```

in aspx code behind - call TypeofEvent in ascx

```
   PaymentInformation1.TypeofEvent(PassClass)
```

Comment: is it because something is wrong with my Class/Page Design? or this is the only way to share values b/w page and controls.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do , you set the class values , but you have to store them somewhere or they will be lost from server when page is refreshed, since the control is rendered first , by the time you set the class in the aspx the control is alreay done with it's code , so you would of had to set the variables already when the ascx control is called

Answer (score 0):

**In webusercontroll globally declare below**

```
public int varriable1{ get; set; }

public int varriable2{ get; set; }
```

**In webusercontroll accessing variable1 and variable2 into variable 1 and 2 respectively**

```
int a=variable1;
int b=variable2;
```

**In yourpage.aspx passing variable into your webusercontroll**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        PostComments_global1.varriable1= 6; //PostComments_global1 is your webuseruser controll id
        PostComments_global1.varriable2= 6;
    }
}
```